# Android Fill Data Array Dynamic

Tags: java, android

I'm stucked with filling an Array dynamic.

I can't find the solution. Normal I would fill the array just by any loop.

It's not working in this case I really spent hours to find a solution.

I found an example to use a custom list in android. works fine.

I create a object Test.

```
public class Test {
public int icon;
public int PB;
public String title;
public Test(){
    super();
}

public Test(int icon, String title, int PB) {
    super();
    this.icon = icon;
    this.title = title;
    this.PB = PB;
}
```

}

and fill it static here works fine. But I don't get how to fill it dynamic.

```
Test test_data[] = new Test[]
    {
        new Test(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Test 1", 10),
        new Test(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Test 2", 100)
    };
```

Comment: .... what dynamic means?

Comment: I'm getting data from a database and want to fill this object with the data everytime the activity starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dynamic assigning of data to an array as is follows:

```
 Test [] test_data = 
{
    new Test(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Test 1", 10),
    new Test(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Test 2", 100)
};
```

**EDIT:**

this can be done only in the first time you instance the array. if you already know how big the array is gonna be you should do this:

```
Test [] test_array = new Test[size];
for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    //DO STUFF
}
```

if you don;t know the size from the start what you should do is use a ListArray and then convert it to a simple array (or not), here is the code for that:

```
ListArray<Test> list = new ListArray<Test>();
// INSERT VALUES

public Test[] listToArray(ArrayList<Test> list) {
     Test [] result = new Test [list.size());
     for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        result[i] = list.get(i);
     }
     return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I knew theres a simple sultion i didn't get because my mind was stuck!

Comment: But well wait I have been too fast. Can you give me an example filling this by a loop? I'm really stucked :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use ArrayList instead of static array.

```
    In case of array u have to define the size at compile time and then add objects to it like:

    Test test_data[] = new Test[10];
    test_data[0] = new Test(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Test 1", 10);
    test_data[1] = new Test(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Test 2", 100);
    ....................
```

I tried the code above. This is what giving me the NULL Pointer Exception.

```
I'm getting data from a database and want to fill this object with the data everytime the activity starts


 You have to use ArrayList like:

 ArrayList<Test> test_data = new ArrayList<Test>;

 test_data.add(new Test(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Test 1", 10));
 test_data.add(new Test(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Test 2", 100));

..........
And clear ArrayList by test_data.clear()
```

Comment: I tried the first Code Example he gave me. If I use an ArrayList I have to restructe the whole code.

Comment: I took the first code example and i got an the exception. If I change to an ArrayList i have to change a lot. So I'm looking for a way to avoid this.

Comment: Tried it over and over now its working due any magic reason! Thanks alot.

Comment: @HimanshuMohta, you have some errors in your code. since it has already been edited, I can't fix them, but you should notice that ArrayList should call a constructor (`new ArrayList<Test>()`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the array.  Since you are using a database, the data must be coming from a cursor, so you can do this:

```
Test test_data[] = new Test[cursor.getCount()]
```

That will create a slot for each record in your cursor.  Then you can run through your loop and populate it.

Comment: The Size isnt the Problem. I tried this static It's giving me a NULL Pointer Exception.